unable to get the proper steps of doing the blob container copy data activity in ADF across two different subscriptions in same tenant
how to copy the fileshare data between the subscriptions of storage accounts - scenario given in description
Using the same solution given from the above question I tried to implement for blob containers across the storage accounts in different subscriptions which are public access enabled.
When Coming to lInked service step from that solution, I cannot do this step @{linkedService().filesharename} because here it is blob storage service.
Can anyone help me on this.
Scenario:
In the Same Azure Tenant, we have 2 storage accounts in 2 subscriptions. In 1st Subscription - blob container storage account, we have data in different blob containers such as:

blobcontainer1uat
blobcontainer1uat

We need to move the data to the 2nd subscription - blob container storage account which has blob containers like:

blobcontainer1stg
blobcontainer1stg

In Simple Context, we have to move data from Fileshare1uat to fileshare1stg and same to next blob containers.

In the case of Fileshare, the fileshare names should be specified in the linked service itself, so that's why we need to use linked service parameters in that scenario.
In this case, as you want to copy the data between the containers, the blob containers can be specified at the dataset level itself. So, there is no need to use linked service parameters. To specify the container, you need to use only the dataset parameters.
First you need to create two Blob storage linked service for your storage accounts in different subscriptions. There is no need to use any parameters here, create linked service like below.

Similarly, create another one for the target blob storage account.
Now, make an array with source and target container names and give to the pipeline array parameter.
[
{
"source_container":"sourcecontainer1",
"target_container":"target1"
},
{
"source_container":"sourcecontainer2",
"target_container":"target2"
}
]

Create Binary datasets for the source and target and while creation leave the filepath of those as empty. After creation, create a dataset parameter container_name of string type and use that in the container name of the file path in the dataset.

Do the same for the target Binary dataset.
Take For-Each and give the containers list to it. Here, inside for-loop, we need to two copy activities. One for the folders of the container and another is for the files which are in the container root level.
sourcecontainer
    folder1
    folder2 // One copy activity to copy these folders
    file1.csv
    file2.csv // Another copy activity to copy these files to the target container

In the first copy activity give the source and sink dataset configurations like below.
Source:

Sink:

In the second copy activity, give the configurations like below.
Source:

Sink:

Now, debug the pipeline, it will give the desired results.


Give us sometime. Checking the Table ADF Pipeline for various activities. Will get back on this before next monday. thank you

Sure, let me know if it's not working.

could you please paste your complete pipeline image in the answer because in the foreach activity setting - items field, what value i need to paste ? (https://i.imgur.com/TgG3tc0.png)

Also, what if the folder 1 and folder 2 contains the data and also subfolders inside it. Do I have to edit the wildcard path from the source dataset in copydata1 & 2 activity?

Do I need to add parameter to the pipeline by specifying the blob container SAS token for both the storage accounts and then web activity  before foreach activity?

First you need to create an array of objects for the source and target container names like I have given at the start of this. Create an array parameter in the pipeline and give this array as default value to it. Use this parameter as the input to the For-each expression like @pipeline().parameters.<parameter_name>.  If your web activity gives the containers list, then you need to give that to the for-each expression. And, It will copy all the subfolders and files inside the folder1 and folder2.

As I have mentioned in the answer, you need to create two linked services for two storage accounts and create two datasets for those respectively. There is no need of parameters for the linked services. Parameters are only for the container names in those datasets. You can use whatever the authentication you have for those while linked service creation, just change the subscription as per the storage account.

can you show pipeline parameters and also the web activity in the answer because web activity (list containers) is succeeded but the result is not only list, along with some extra data. unable to fetch only the container names to for each activity. So, could you please post the full answer

I am not using any web activity to fetch the container names, I am manually creating an array parameter in the pipeline section and giving the above container array as the default value for it. Then I am giving that parameter to the For-Each activity. If you are getting the required containers list from the web activity, can you show the web activity output image(total output), so that I can figure out the required expression for the For-Each?

Please give us some time, we will back to this. We are figuring the table storage copy as we are facing some issues  and you only should help us in clearing that table storage copy data issue also.
